# Converting a number to next 0.5 in excel

Tags: excel-2007, excel-2010

Please help in to convert number to next 0.5 in excel.

example:
1.30  converts to 1.5,

1.499 converts to 1.5

1.510 converts to 2

4.012 converts to 4.5

4.5006 converts to 5

0.12   converts to 0.5

0.731 converts to 1

i.e converts to next 0.5.

I tried some functions but couldnt get a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Nice Question!

The ROUNDUP Formula is

```
=IF(ROUNDUP(A1,0)-A1 >= .5 , ROUNDUP(A1,0)-.5, ROUNDUP(A1,0))
```

**Explanation**

If it takes 0.5 or more to round the number up to the nearest integer, then we can use the rounded integer - 0.5 to bring the number to the nearest .5

If it takes less than 0.5 to round it up, then the rounded up integer is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A much cleaner solution to use is

```
floor(A1 * 2 + 0.5) / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CEILING function:

```
=CEILING(A1,0.5)
```